# Why are git-stash options not prefixed with dashes?

Tags: git

Most commands I've worked with use dashes to receive option argumentses:

```
git branch --all
git checkout --quiet
git apply --verbose
.
.
and so on
```

Whereas `git-stash` is different, it takes what I'd categorize as 'options' without dashes:

```
git stash list
git stash show
git stash drop
.
.
```

What is the reason behind this (imho) inconsistency? Are `list`, `show`, `drop` different sort of arguments than `all`, `quiet` or `verbose`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`git stash list|drop|show` etc. are *not* option arguments, they're commands.

In `git branch [--all]`, *branch* is the command (or verb), and *all* qualifies it.

In `git stash save` however, *save* is the verb: *stash* names a subsystem which implements this command.

Compare `git submodule`: this is another subsystem with its own commands.

Answer (score 1):

They are distinct commands, not different views on / modifications of a command. Therefore I think it's correct that Git does not use the option syntax here.